# Symfony2: force stop code execution after sendiing Response headers

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-foundation

What is the correct way to stop code execution after sending Response headers, but without using `exit()`?

I know the script SHOULD return a Response, but how can I force it to be returned from outside of a Controller, for example from a service?

Lets say my service's method does return a Response this way:

```
return RedirectResponse($url)->send();
```

But in another place it can return other things. So what I can do is to check what it does actually return:

```
$result = $myService->doSomething();
if ($result instanceof RedirectResponse) {
    return $result;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to avoid checking result type in every place where I use my service, BUT I would like to see the returned response in Profiler/logs (if I use exit() I can't).

Is there a way to force kernel terminate?

---

**EDIT:**

Actually the service is used in event before any controller, so I want to do redirect before any controller execution. So maybe a way to omit controller execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do it. All I had to do is to terminate the kernel before exit - it does dispatch all after-response events (like profiling, logging etc.).

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
exit();
```

If anyone would found better way do to this, please answer so I can switch the mark.

Answer (score 1):

> A controller is a PHP callable you create that takes information from the HTTP request and creates and returns an HTTP response (as a Symfony Response object).

The only concern for a Controller is to process a request and return a response. Having a Service handle a Response object is probably a bad design choice.

In any case, you could just die/exit your controller and use Kernel events to hook in the Request/Response flow and inspect the returned Response. Probably the terminate event  is the right choice http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html

Comment: Actually the service is used in event before any controller, so I want to do redirect before any controller execution. I just wanted to make the question more general.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Ok, got it! At the same page you can find even the request event. It should be what are you searching for. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event